# PayPal Express Checkout API ignoring SOLUTIONTYPE=Mark

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I'm trying to disable card payments via Paypal depending on certain criteria and despite passing SOLUTIONTYPE=Mark when making my NVP call, card payments are still available. Paypal Account Optional is enabled on the account and the API version is 204.

Has anyone one encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

To completely disable the function, you need to turn off the PayPal Account Optional in your account. Once you have turned it off, the PayPal checkout page would only display the "Login to PayPal " and the "Create a PayPal account" option.